# Styles not working properly in an specific page

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a Newbie in React Native. And I'm trying to create a login screen with a normal "ENTER" button and Facebook and google "login with" buttons. For the social network buttons, I used expo vector-icons, but for the normal button, I created a .js file to host the button code so I can use it on other pages. The problem is: the button's styles are not being applied when I'm using it on this specific screen, for some reason... Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code for the login screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome, Zocial } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import SubmitButton from '../../shared/SubmitButton';
import FocusAwareStatusBar from '../../shared/StatusBar';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 background: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'flex-start',
   paddingHorizontal: 16
 },


 loginform: {
   alignSelf: "stretch",
   marginTop: 64,
 },

 inputs: {
   alignSelf: "stretch",
   fontFamily: "Roboto_400Regular",
   fontSize: 14,
   color: "#000",
   borderBottomColor: '#dcdcdc',
   borderBottomWidth: 0.8,
   paddingBottom: 8,
   paddingLeft: 12,
 },

 loginSocialNetworkContainer: {
   justifyContent: "center",
   alignSelf: "center",
   backgroundColor: '#fff',
   elevation: 6,
   borderRadius: 6,
   marginBottom: 8,
 },

 loginSocialNetwork: {
   alignContent: "center",
   justifyContent: "center",
   width: 232,
   height: 40,
   borderRadius: 2,

 },

 loginSocialNetworkText: {
   fontSize: 12,
   fontFamily: "Roboto_400Regular",
   color: "#f7f7f7",
 },


});

export default function Login({ navigation }) {
 return (
   <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     <FocusAwareStatusBar barStyle='light-content' backgroundColor='#88c9bf' />


     <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.background}>

       <View style={styles.loginform}>
         <TextInput style={{ ...styles.inputs, marginBottom: 20 }}
           placeholder="Nome de usuário"
           autoCorrect={false}
           onChangeText={() => { }}
         />

         <TextInput style={{ ...styles.inputs, marginBottom: 52 }}
           placeholder="Senha"
           autoCorrect={false}
           secureTextEntry={true}
           onChangeText={() => { }}
         />



         <SubmitButton text='ENTRAR' onPress={() => { }} />






         <View style={{ ...styles.loginSocialNetworkContainer, marginTop: 72 }}>
           <FontAwesome.Button name='facebook-square' style={styles.loginSocialNetwork} size={17.5} iconStyle={{ color: '#f7f7f7' }} backgroundColor="#194f7c" onPress={() => { }}>
             <Text style={styles.loginSocialNetworkText}>ENTRAR COM FACEBOOK</Text>
           </FontAwesome.Button>
         </View>

         <View style={styles.loginSocialNetworkContainer}>
           <Zocial.Button name='googleplus' style={styles.loginSocialNetwork} size={15} iconStyle={{ color: '#f7f7f7', marginRight: 9.3, marginLeft: 0.3 }} backgroundColor="#f25f5c" onPress={() => { }}>
             <Text style={{ ...styles.loginSocialNetworkText, paddingRight: 14 }}>ENTRAR COM GOOGLE</Text>
           </Zocial.Button>
         </View>


       </View>

     </KeyboardAvoidingView>
   </SafeAreaView>
 );
}
```

And here is the SubmitButton's code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function SubmitButton({ text, onPress, color }) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
                <View style={ color != null ? {...styles.button, backgroundColor: color} :styles.button} >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{text}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignSelf: "center",
        backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
        elevation: 6,
        borderRadius: 2,
        width: 232,
        height: 40,
    },
    button: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: '#88c9bf',
        width: 232,
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 2,
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontFamily: "Roboto_400Regular",
        fontSize: 12,
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        textAlign: "center",
        color: '#434343',

    }
});
```

As we can see, the elevation is not getting applied nor the button can be
pressed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Import React in your login page

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome, Zocial } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import SubmitButton from '../../shared/SubmitButton';
import FocusAwareStatusBar from '../../shared/StatusBar';
```

Comment: Sorry, it is in the code but for some reason I didn't put it in the question's code. I'm going to edit.

Comment: Look at this example, it worked for me, check it out 
https://snack.expo.io/@stealkiller06/ece356

Comment: I'm being able to click, but the font and the elevation are not working properly

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const LotsOfStyles = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.red}>just red</Text>
        <Text style={styles.bigBlue}>just bigBlue</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.bigBlue, styles.red]}>bigBlue, then red</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.red, styles.bigBlue]}>red, then bigBlue</Text>
      </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  bigBlue: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});

export default LotsOfStyles;
```

Comment: please provide more details about your answer

Comment: I did that in the SubmitButton file, but somehow my button is not getting correctly styled.